# How can I apply Clamp.js to multiple elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress

I am attempting to us clamp.jp to truncate blog feed titles.

I have successfully implemented it but it only affects the first element with the defined class.

I've tried to add a loop but I don't think it works with how I have the javascript set up.

Below is how it is currently set but it only gets the first element:

```
var module = document.querySelector(".box p");

$clamp(module, {clamp: 3});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelector will just take the first element matching the query. You should use querySelectorAll and the loop through it.

```
const modules = document.querySelectorAll('.box p');

// Make sure our query found anything
if(modules) {
    // Loop through each module and apply the clamping.
    modules.forEach((module, index) => {
        $clamp(module, {clamp: 3});
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks. This worked. Only just started trying to learn JS rather than copying and pasting so only just getting my head around the basics.